# How to check MySQL table is not replaced

Tags: mysql, ddl

I'm digging on MySQL's online ddl (5.7)

For some operations, it support ALGORITHM such as INPLACE, COPY.

This is I understood

- INPLACE modifies original table
- COPY creates temporary table -> copies all records to it -> and replace original table

Plus, this link refers that adding index to a table does not rebuild table
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html

but, after I add index and check tables CREATE_TIME it is updated

```
CREATE DATABASE db;
USE db;


CREATE TABLE hello(id int primary key auto_increment, col varchar(20));

SELECT CREATE_TIME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='db' and TABLE_NAME='hello';


ALTER TABLE hello ADD INDEX `idx_col` (col), ALGORITHM=INPLACE;

# CREATE TIME is updated
SELECT CREATE_TIME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='db' and TABLE_NAME='hello';
```

I'm not sure whether CREATE_TIME doesn't actually mean table creation time, or
whether table is rebuilt even with ALGORITHM=INPLACE specified.

Could anyone help me find out what is going on here?

Comment: why does it make a difference to you?  is the alter table not fast enough?  or is it that it is locking the table when you don't want it to?

Comment: `CREATE_TIME` for `InnoDB` tables shows recent alter if it ever had.

Comment: You can try with `show table status where name = your-table-name`  and for InnoDB tables will be the same, most recent alter time

Comment: @ErgestBasha Does every alter update `CREATE_TIME`?
I'm confused about the difference between `In Place`and `Copy`.

As far as I know, `In Place` updates the original table and not recreates it, and `Copy` copies all records to new table and removes the original one.

Am I misundertanding these concepts?

Comment: @ysth 
Looking at the Index operation table(Table 14.10) from the [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html), what I understood is that adding index in places original table and does not rebuild it.


I thought in placing table means using the same table, so I expected UPDATE_TIME to be updated and CREATE_TIME to remain same.

Is it that I'm having misconception with `In Place`?

Comment: @Kali it is listed as a bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90219